# PyCharm Kite AI autocomplete is not working

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, kite

I have recently bought PyCharm Professional and added the Kite AI Autocomplete plugin but it's not showing proper suggestions of packages. Is there any way where I can reset or check Kite settings?

[image: PyCharm Kite Error]

Comment: You may try to update it or try using sublime text instead of pycharm

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are options to check the settings for PyCharm-integrated Kite Plugin.
The settings are accessible inside your opened PyCharm program via File> Settings. Please enter kite as a search string inside the Settings window.

Possibly those 2 steps should solve your problem:

1. Check whether the installed kite plugin is properly enabled
   [image: Check whether the installed kite plugin is properly enabled]
2. Start Kite at startup
   [image: Start Kite at startup]